# Import constant from external file into python

Tags: python, pylint

I would like to import a constant from an external file. I have two files in one directory.
`constants.py` file:

```
SOME_CONSTANT = 'something'
```

And import this into `settings.py`

```
import constants

someVariable = constants.SOME_CONSTANT
```

But pylint write that `Module 'constants' has no 'SOME_CONSTANT' member`

Comment: Think it should be `someVariable = constants.SOME_CONSTANT`. `secrets` isn't defined.

Comment: It was necessary to add a point for import local file import .constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't really tell how you made your constants, but ideally you'd want to store them in your class.

```
#Constants.Py
class Province:
    CITY = 'Toronto'

#Settings.Py
from Constants import Province
someVariable = Province.CITY
>>> 'Toronto'
```